# Deleting duplicates and replacing entries in a row – Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

In this project, I am looking to delete duplicates based on the ID number by keeping the latest entries. Additionally, I want to keep every cell in Column D and onward from the previous entries. This ultimately means that the latest entries will be replaced in the previous entries’ row. Please see tables below for more clarity:

[image: Example of results before and after macro]

Based on the example given above, the result I am looking for is to:

- Delete duplicates based on the ID from columns A to C and keep the latest entries
- Keep Columns D to H from the previous entries
- Replace previous entries by the latest ones in the previous entries’ row.

In other words: Update Columns A to C without modifying Columns D to H

So, the initial code that I had was as follow. It only kept the previous entries and kept columns D to H:

```
Sub Delete_Duplicates()
Sheet5.Range("$A$1:$H$29999").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1) _
    , Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

The table below shows what i would obtain:
[image: Result after first code]

The next code I did was to keep the newest entries, but this deletes my entries in column D to H:

```
Sub Delete_Duplicates_2()
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, n As Long
Dim Lst As Long, nRng As Range
Set Rng = Sheet5.Range("$A$2:$H$29999")
Lst = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For n = Lst To 1 Step -1
     If Not .Exists(Range("A" & n).Value) Then
        .Add Range("A" & n).Value, Nothing
    Else
        If nRng Is Nothing Then
            Set nRng = Range("A" & n)
        Else
            Set nRng = Union(nRng, Range("A" & n))
        End If
End If
Next n
If Not nRng Is Nothing Then 
nRng.EntireRow.Delete
End With
End Sub
```

The table below shows what I would obtain:
[image]

I am open to any suggestions and thank you for your help!

Comment: I need some clarification - are you looking to keep the comments in column D? Is the first table example your expected outcome?

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple column D entries associated with the same ID on different rows?  If so, how do you want to handle that?

Comment: @dwirony: Yes I would like to keep all the comments in Column D to H. And yes, the first table example result is the expected outcome.

Comment: @both: One thing to note is that only the first entries of each ID will have comments. all the others will not (the example reflects that). Hope that was clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution - since you're essentially working with a string in your date column, we have to split out the number and test to see if it's greater or less than the other week's number:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Delete_Duplicates()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim id As String, weeknum As Long

    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        id = Cells(i, 1).Value
        weeknum = Split(Cells(i, 3).Value, " ")(1)

        For j = i - 1 To 2 Step -1
            If Cells(j, 1).Value = id Then
                If Split(Cells(j, 3).Value, " ")(1) < weeknum Then
                    Rows(j).Delete
                    i = i - 1
                Else
                    Rows(i).Delete
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: Hi Dwirony,

What I am looking for is not to have the latest date, but the last entry (in the example I have given, for ID 458, it would be Week 4, which my last codes successfully gives me). I am also looking in having the comments from the first entries of ID's. Hope these clarification help and thank you for your answer!